# How to integrate array in echo txt?

Tags: php

A simple question, but I could not find a solution

```
$page = 'newnews';
$link = 'http://website.net/$page/sport';
echo $link;
```

The web server shows me the text as:

```
http://website.net/$page/sport
```

And Its needs to be:

```
http://website.net/newnews/sport
```

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'`...

Comment: @Soolie oh so easy ^^ works thank you!